# Sitecore 9 Installation fails on Solr (core is already defined)

Tags: powershell, solr, lucene, sitecore

I realize this may be a long shot, and the caveat is that I'm a newbie when it comes to Solr.  But I'm reaching the end of my rope here.

I'm attempting to install Sitecore 9 from a powershell script that is included in the installation manual and seen at https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2017/10/how-to-install-sitecore-9-with-the-sitecore-install-framework/ , which basically kicks off several sequential instances of Install-SitecoreConfiguration.  I am running into an issue in xconnect-solr.json when it attempts to create a solr core, which it does by first copying the necessary configs into the core folder and then running a create.

Of course, when it does that, Solr responds with the error "Could not create a new core in C:\solr-6.6.2\server\solr\sc90_xdbas another core is already defined there" and the whole process ends.

I'm running solr 6.6.2 but have also tried with the 7 versions and 6.6.1 to no avail, all under https.

I figure it's a pretty specific question, but I can't believe Sitecore 9 installers aren't running into this.

Any help anyone can offer would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone.  What turned out to be the issue was that I needed to run the solr Windows service with the "-f" flag.  Don't ask me why, but for whatever reason Sitecore installation worked after that point.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

That means you already have a core with same name, Solr core name is found inside the core folder, in a file called "**core.properties**", open it and you will find the core name , Make sure you don't have duplicates cores with same name, if you do, remove them.

You probably ran the installation script twice with same Solr core name, which caused that error.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code with a Solr version earlier than 5.5.